# flv.js can not play with avc1 codecs

Tags: javascript, live-streaming

I'm new with livestream, now i'm using flv.js and h5 (video tag) to streaming http , all is alright until logger.js(from flv.js) log is: *[MSEController] > Received Initialization Segment, mimeType: audio/mp4;codecs=avc1.64001f*, and then my player is black and muted.

Before that issue, all log is : *[MSEController] > Received Initialization Segment, mimeType: audio/mp4;codecs=mp4a.40.5*. The different is mimeType.

So can i must do to fix this issue ?

Thank everyone for help.

Comment: The mime type is correct. Avc1 is just another name for h.264. Whatever the problem you are having, it has nothing to do with the mime type.

Comment: @szatmary thank you, now i will resolve this problem by another way.